# Can neuroevolution be used for solving tasks other than games?

Tags: neural-networks, applications, evolutionary-algorithms, neuroevolution

I'm seeing a lot of examples of neuroevolution techniques involving games or robot problems. Can neuroevolution be used for solving tasks other than games? For example, how could you transform a CSV file of psychological data to determine the best life actions you can get from a self-report questionnaire?

Comment: Medical Diagnostics is a promising area for AI in general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence_in_healthcare#Current_Research